# Does Ubuntu One have a payment API?

Tags: ubuntu-one, application-development, python, ubuntu-one-api

Do Ubuntu One has an payment API,

I can integrate in my ubuntu-app(python)?

I would use it to add an easy donate dialog.

So end user can choose an default monthly donate amount, and how many months it will run for.

**UPDATE:**

I has contact Canonical abort this, and Joshua Hoover reply:

*Eventually we'll provide a way to do this but it's going to be further
out in the future.*

**NB:** *my question/email to Canonical was only containing the first tree lines..*

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you plan to do? Accept payments for virtual goods; help people subscribe to paid Ubuntu One plans; something else?

Comment: I would use it to add an easy donate dialog. end user can choose an default monthly donate amount, and how many months it will run for..

Comment: @Voidcode Please also update the question to be more specific about what you want, so that it's easier to find that information, rather than leaving it as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, from the [Ubuntu One APIs page](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/), it looks like the *Account Information API* is read-only and does not currently allow you to upgrade/subscribe a user to a paid account. However, it will let you access the user's account info and whether he/she has a paid plan.

From [this page](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/account_info/cloud):

> GET https://one.ubuntu.com/api/account/
>
> Return information about the user account.
>
> Requests to this API must be signed with a valid Ubuntu One OAuth token.
>
> Returns a JSON object of information about the user account.

```
    {
.....
        "subscription": {
            "description": (string) user-displayable description of account
            "currency": (string) three-character currency code for account payments
            "started": (string) ISO 8601 date for subscription start
            "is_paid": (boolean) subscription paid status
            "expires": (string) ISO 8601 date for subscription expiry
            "id": (int) Internal U1 subscription ID
            "price": (float) subscription cost
            "trial": (boolean) is subscription a trial?
            "qty": (int) subscription quantity
            "upgrade_available": (boolean) is upgrade available?
            "name": (string) user-displayable name of subscription
        },
......
```

Comment: Also, even if that API did allow you to add a subscription or buy more storage space, it would only be for Ubuntu One. It would not be for accepting payments for features in your own app, for say DLC or donating to a charity, or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One is a data synchronization and availability service. The Ubuntu One account API is not relevant here, as it is for accounts for that service, only.

I don't believe there is yet a public API, necessary legal agreements, or any standard way to use the payments processing service which powers Ubuntu One or the Ubuntu Store. If you wish to discuss the possibility of using such a service in applications developed for Ubuntu, you should [contact Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/contact), to engage in business development and partnership discussions, around such a payments service.